# Birthday probability: wrong output

Tags: java, random

The code below is supposed to generate random day of year, and matche every 2 people who have same birthday. This is know as birthday problem. The code works but the output is wrong.

```
public double simulate(int size, int count) {

    Random random = new Random();

    double x[] = new double[size];

    double matches = 0;

    boolean isMatch = false;

    random.setSeed(count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {

            x[j] = random.nextInt(365);

            for (int k = j + 1; k < size; k++) {

                if (x[j] == x[k]) {

                    matches++;

                    isMatch = true;

                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isMatch) {

                isMatch = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return (matches/count)*100;
}
```

and here is the Expected output result

```
 simulate(number of people,number of simulation)
 simulate(5, 10000) output = 2.71
 simulate(7, 5000)  output = 5.34 
 simulate(2, 10000) output = 0.27 
 simulate(9, 10000) output = 9.47 
 simulate(30, 20000) output = 70.675
 simulate(15, 50000) output = 25.576
 simulate(35, 50000) output = 81.434
 simulate(45, 50000) output = 94.2
```

and this what Actual output :

```
     simulate(5, 10000) output = 2.54
     simulate(7, 5000)  output = 5.64 
     simulate(2, 10000) output = 0.18
     simulate(9, 10000) output = 9.05
     simulate(30, 20000) output = 68.98
     simulate(15, 50000) output = 25.12
     simulate(35, 50000) output = 79.90
     simulate(45, 50000) output = 92.99
```

thanks for you time .

Comment: why are you using `doubles` in `double x[] = new double[size]; double matches = 0;` ?

Comment: Okay, try to find out what a "simulation" is. If you do a simulation using a random generator, you will not get the exact same results as some expected value. If you use enough random samples, then the result will be close. In your case, the results are all pretty close to your expected values. So your program seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @ScaryWombat size is the number of people and matches get increased every time  2 values match

Comment: but as per the code `x[j] = random.nextInt(365);` you are storing `int` values not `doubles`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt its a part of an assignment and they use an auto-grading system ,  the system will refuses mysubmission if it dosent match the expected values

Comment: can yo post an [MCVE]  ? with a main that runs it ?

Comment: @MohamedRa Have you tried? Because nobody will be able to submit if that's the case, unless you have a series of if-statements for each size/count pair and then return the expected value.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt yes I tried couple of times and failed :)

Comment: @ScaryWombat  what do you suggest ,shall I use `nextDouble()` instead of `nextInt()` since the `nextDouble()` dose not accept a parameter . sorry if I'm  wrong

Comment: NO, `int x[] = new int[size];`  You are dealing with `int` values not doubles

Comment: How do you know to set the seed to `count`? Was that an instruction? `random.setSeed(count);`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt yes , so everyone can have the same output .

Answer (score 1):

There is one big problem in your code. You're initializing the array `x` with random data, but before you've fully initialized it, you are already checking if there are two values that are the same. At that point, the end of the array will not yet be fully initialized. Change that to:

```
        // First fully filly the array x with values
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            x[j] = random.nextInt(365);
        }

        // And then go checking for duplicates
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            // etc.
```

After that, your results will be a closer to the expected output, but still not exactly the same. That could have something to do with the exact value for the random seed.

Comment: yes its more closer now , without the seed I can get the expected value but only after a couple of attempts, thank you .